# Got 403 error (forbidden) on saving a post on inserting styles to the text in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, error-handling, styles

#### ABOUT SERVER

I've installed the newest version of **Wordpress** on my own VPS running **Apache** and **PHP 7.2**

The Apache was installed automatically when I had installed centos web panel (CWP)

---

#### ABOUT PROBLEM

In Wordpress, when I want to publish or update a Post **containing HTML styles or classes**, the page redirects to a *403 error page* with this content:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/post.php on this server.

For example, when I **change** the text **font** or **color**, the post could not be saved!

---

I've deactivated all plugins and tested again but nothing changed.

Comment: Check that the SElinux isnt interfering with apache/php.  I have had that happen with centos and nginx.  Also check to make sure that apache is running with the correct user and group

Comment: Do as @jdubu423 says... sounds like a permission issue

Comment: @jdubu423 the selinux is disabled and apache user and group is in a correct situation, but however the problem is on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got myself.

the problem was due to `mod security` of my CentOS Web Panel (CWP) I'd installed.

The XSS mod security rule also prevents injecting special HTML tags.

**To disable XSS rule:**

- add a `removal rule` to file: `global_disabled_rules.conf` in apache mod-security-owasp folder.
  in centos web panel, the Apache folder is in `/usr/local/apache`

OR

- remove or rename this file: `modsecurity_crs_41_xss_attacks.conf` 
  in this path ( path is correct for CWP panel ): `/usr/local/apache/modsecurity-owasp-old/base_rules/`

> OR you can simply, completely disable mod security

---

Consider that, I first disabled my firewall, but nothing got changed but when I disabled mod-security, the 403 Forbidden error had gone away.

So notice that firewall and mod-security are two separated things.